# Reduction modulo p of a linear group over the rational numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, algebraic-groups

A paper (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.3158v2.pdf) contains the following theorem:

> Suppose $\mathbb{G}$ is a connected, simply connected, semisimple algebraic group defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $\Gamma \leq \mathbb{G}(\mathbb{Q})$ be a finitely generated Zariski-dense subgroup. Denote by $\mathbb{G}_p$ the smooth reduction of $\mathbb{G}$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Then for all sufficiently large prime numbers $p$, the reduction $\Gamma_p$ of $\Gamma$ is equal to $\mathbb{G}_p (\mathbb{F}_p)$.

What confuses me is the so-called smooth reduction happening. I would understand this if $\mathbb{G}$ were defined over $\mathbb{Z}$ because then we can just take all the matrix entries modulo $p$, but what can it mean for a rational number to be reduced in this way, if that is indeed what is happening?

**EDIT**

It would help to have also an example of how this reduction would apply to an element of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Q})$.

**EDIT 2**

I received the following answer to this question in a chatroom, but it is far too complicated for me to understand. In particular, I know little to no algebraic geometry, and I am only beginning to learn category theory.

> $\mathbb{G}$ is defined over $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Q}$, so it's of finite type (over $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Q}$), and so you can take the ideal sheaf locally and restrict it to $\mathbb{Z}$.
>
> -- hodgeclass

Comment: When $G$ is a split connected reductive algebraic group over $\mathbb{Q}$, there exists a Chevalley group $\mathbb{G}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$, and it is uniquely determined up to $\mathbb{Z}$-group isomorphism. However when $G$ is not split, this is no longer unique. I do not believe your hypotheses imply the group is split.

Comment: @RghtHndSd: I'm afraid I do not understand your comment. Are you saying the theorem is wrong?

Comment: No, only that the theory of Chevally groups (which is where one can find "canonical" integral models of reductive groups) does not seem to apply.

Answer (score 0):

The top of page 2 in the linked paper on the arXiv seems to suggest this is the definition:

> Let $\mathbb{G}$ be a connected simply connected, semisimple algebraic group defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ with a fixed embedding $\mathbb{G} \hookrightarrow GL_n$. Then
>   $$\mathbb{G}(\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{G}(\mathbb{Q}) \cap GL_n(\mathbb{Z}).$$

This allows one to consider the reductions. I do not think that $\mathbb{G}(\mathbb{Z})$ is independent of the embedding chosen, but again the arXiv paper seems to suggest it is for primes outside of some finite set.